# implement configurable product with specific price for every combination of attributes

Tags: php, magento-1.7

does anyone know how to achieve this functionality?

We currently have a single product with different colors and sizes and for each combination, there is an specific price for it.

We need something similar to configurable product but instead of adjusting the price based on its attribute, we need to set an specific price for each combination.

We are using magento 1.7

Weve tried using simple configurable plugin
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

together with the patch 
https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple
but failed to make it work.

Is there any other way for magento to achieve this functionality?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a single attribute and adjust the prices based on this attribute, instead of having more than one attribute.